# Send SQL query Result set to an email ID using Pentaho

Tags: sql, email, pentaho

I am quite new to `PDI` and I'm trying to do something as given below :

```sql
SELECT table_names FROM schema.table_details WHERE last_run_date < current_date
```

`table_details` have information about all the tables in different schema and their last run time. I want to know which tables didn'nt update today and send the list of tables as subject or as a body of the email (I prefer them to get as a subject or in body rather than a file).

How can I do this using `PDI`?

I have tried using `Set variables`, but it can hold only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have implemented this in a simple way instead of getting emails for all tables i get one email for all tables with daily status.

you can perform the same in 2 ways

Method 1

1. use your query in table input step
2. connect a hop to excel output where you have the status of your file
3. you can then email the same file as attachment using email step. ( you want to get information in email content, you can stream the data using 'load file content in memory' and pass the variable in email content)

Method 2. ( this is in case you want tabular formatted email)

1. use your query in table input step and extract using xml output
2. verify if xml is well formed
3. using XSL Transformation change the output to html
4. pass html as part of variable
5. pass the variable in email content

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please elaborate more on the Method 2. If you have a sample one for me to check could you please attach.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Group by step, using the 'Concatenete string separated by' option, with the value as ${line.separator}, this way you will have a single row, containing the full string. With this you can set as variable and utilize a JOB mail step as a body.

[image]