# Sending a table by pentaho spoon email

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

In Pentaho spoon, I'm inputting a table and adding some filters, constants, and calculated fields.
My final step is to e-mail the remaining lines. The mail function sends a separate e-mail for each line - is it possible to send the entire table in the body of the e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in one transformation, the email step for a transformation in Spoon is designed to operate for each input row.

The easiest way would be to end the transformation generating a file with your data and create a job to run the transformation and continue the job sending an email (using the job action) taking that file and sending the data as an attachment.

If you need to send the rows in the mail body and not as an attachment, this old thread offers different methods to achieve it: [Send SQL query Result set to an email ID using Pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522804/send-sql-query-result-set-to-an-email-id-using-pentaho)